# Remove a column comment in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From [Snowflake's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/comment.html) [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html), it's clear how to add or overwrite a comment on a table column, but it doesn't look like you can remove a comment one without re-creating the table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE "My_Table" (
  "my_column" INT
);
ALTER TABLE "My_Table" ALTER "my_column" COMMENT 'New Comment';  -- Works
ALTER TABLE "My_Table" ALTER "my_column" COMMENT NULL; -- Fails
ALTER TABLE "My_Table" ALTER "my_column" COMMENT '';  -- Works, but prefer NULL
```

As shown above, the best I can find is to set the comment to `''`, but I would really prefer it to be null.  Does anyone know how to remove a comment?

Comment: I would say it is not possible. There is no `UNSET COMMENT` for columns(it is for table comment though) and [COMMENT ON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/comment.html) allows only for overwrite. I guess that sth like `SET comment = NULL::TEXT; COMMENT ON "My_Table"."my_column" IS $comment;` will also fail.

Comment: I am curious to see if there's a direct way to do this. If not, you could at least avoid recreating the whole table by just creating a new column. I'm not sure how much faster/less-expensive that would be, compared to copying the whole table, though. `alter table "My_Table" rename column "my_column" to oldcol;
alter table "My_Table" add column "my_column" int;
update "My_Table" set "my_column" = oldcol;
alter table "My_Table" drop column oldcol;
`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Yes, I can verify that using a variable in a DDL is not supported.

Comment: what if you alter without mentioning comment

Answer (score 1):

steps are:

1. create a new column column2
2. update the table so column2 = column1
3. drop column1
4. then rename column2 to column1;

Not sure if its worth the effort, but here goes:

```
alter table my_table add column my_column2 int;

update my_table set my_column2 = my_column;

alter table my_table drop column my_column;

alter table my_table rename column my_column2 to my_column;

describe table my_table ;
```

[image: Validation of Script - Image]

Comment: Thanks; it's unfortunate that this is what we have to resort to, but what you describe appears to be the best option as of July 2021 anyway.